# Forbid IMAP clients create mailboxes in Dovecot

Tags: dovecot, imap

In this specific setup I want to forbid clients to create mailboxes other than the default ones.  I searched for this in the documentation but found nothing.

I'm using Dovecot with virtual users.

Comment: I have not tried, but you should be able to achieve this goal by removing the `create` permission in the user's [ACLs](https://wiki2.dovecot.org/ACL).

Comment: That worked, thanks! Please, answer that so I can mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dovecot supports the IMAP ACL extension, which allows to configure fine-granular mailbox privileges. Among those, there is the `create` permission allowing (or denying) the creation of new (sub)mailboxes.

[Enable the ACL plugin as described in the Dovecot configuration manual](https://wiki2.dovecot.org/ACL) by editing `dovecot.conf` (or the respective `conf.d` files as setup by your distribution). From the Dovecot manual:

```
mail_plugins = acl
protocol imap {
  mail_plugins = $mail_plugins imap_acl
}

plugin {
  # Without global ACLs:
  acl = vfile

  # With global ACL files in /etc/dovecot/dovecot-acls file (v2.2.11+):
  #acl = vfile:/etc/dovecot/dovecot-acl

  # With global ACLs in /etc/dovecot/acls/ directory (obsolete):
  #acl = vfile:/etc/dovecot/acls

  # If enabled, don't try to find dovecot-acl files from mailbox directories.
  # This reduces unnecessary disk I/O when only global ACLs are used. (v2.2.31+)
  #acl_globals_only = yes
}
```

Instead of manually editing the ACL files, using Dovecot's management tool [`doveadm acl`](https://wiki2.dovecot.org/Tools/Doveadm/ACL) is preferred. To remove the create permission, use following command line (don't `delete` the whole ACL, you might also have to `create` one before starting). `-u user` denotes the mailbox owner (ie., the user to change the mailbox for). `id` denotes the user of which you want to modify the ACLs (you can also give access to other users through ACLs), for example `user=user_name` or `anyone`.

```
doveadm acl remove [-u user|-A|-F file] [-S socket_path] mailbox id right [right ...]
```

You might also want to read about [ACL inheritance](https://wiki2.dovecot.org/ACL#ACL_Inheritance), although this is less important as you want to deny creation of new mailboxes anyway.